# Modeling rest response to class

Tags: javascript

In all my JS projects i always used dot notation to access rest response fields. This works great, but sometimes it's needed to perform null checks and if the model is complex we loose very soon the control.

Suppose a response like this (for example, an user):

```
{
    "name": "Joe",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "address": {
        "street": "my street",
        "state": "UK"
    }
}
```

Would be great if this object will be passed to a class `User` and we can safely (and more simply) write:

`user.getName()` (or user.name) and `user.getStreet()` (or user.street) and make all the checks inside the class, for example when calling user.getStreet() is the class responsible to check if the `address` exists.

More in general, how to map an object to a class so we can perform operations and avoid the annoyng dot notation? eg: `user.address.street`

Comment: Write a class and pass the response as an argument when creating an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that you have some level of certainty how to response structure will look like and that you don't have same key names on different levels but it is still dynamic solution that will loop nested data structure and add get method for each property.

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "Joe",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "address": {
    "street": "my street",
    "state": "UK"
  }
}

class User {
  constructor(data = null) {
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
      this.addGetters(data);
    }
  }

  addGetters(data) {
    for (let i in data) {
      if (typeof data[i] === 'object') {
        this.addGetters(data[i])
      }

      this[i] = data[i]

      this[`get${this.capitalize(i)}`] = () => {
        return data[i]
      }
    }
  }

  capitalize(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  }
}

const foo = new User(obj);

console.log(foo.getName())
console.log(foo.getStreet())
console.log(foo.getAddress())
console.log(foo.street)
```

Comment: Very nice and clean solution. But usually, in your JS application you dont care about this and use the "magical" dot notation on the response, or your wrap the response in models ?

Comment: @Mistre83 I try to create data structure in such a way to avoid too much nested data and then also slice it into multiple parts on the front-end by separating it into multiple state properties. But it also depends on what kind of project you are building. You can also look into https://lodash.com/docs/#get  and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining